# Confusion about Java 10 grammar specification (FieldAccess seems wrong)

Tags: java, grammar, language-specifications

I am working on some syntax tree synchronising tools and try to write a parser for a small subset of Java; I am confused about the Java 10 grammar specification and consider that the definition of `FieldAccess` is wrong.

In my opinion, the grammar of `FieldAccess` is something like `obj.x`, in which `obj` is an identifier (or something alike).

But it seems that the grammar for `FieldAccess` cannot produce `obj.x`

```
FieldAccess:
Primary . Identifier 
super . Identifier 
TypeName . super . Identifier
```

because the definition of `Primary` is

```
Primary:
PrimaryNoNewArray 
ArrayCreationExpression
```

in which neither of the nonterminals can be `Identifier`.

I believe the grammar for `FieldAccess` should be
`PostfixExpression . Identifier`,
where `PostfixExpression` is the nonterminal ‘one layer higher than `Primary`’:

```
PostfixExpression:
Primary 
ExpressionName 
PostIncrementExpression 
PostDecrementExpression
```

So that `ExpressionName` can eventually produce an identifier as desired

```
ExpressionName:
Identifier
AmbiguousName . Identifier
```

Can anyone give me some comments, or kindly tell me a proper place to report this issue?
I can only find a place for reporting bugs in implementations of the Java Platform, but hardly a place for reporting errors in the language specification.

Comment: Interesting question, but the part that asks for the correct bug tracker to use is unfortunately off topic here.

Comment: It's not a bug. `FieldAccess` intentionally does not match `id.id` - `ExpressionName` does. The note on [Primary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-Primary) explains why that is.

Comment: @sepp2k Yes, but the problem is that `Primary` cannot be `ExpressionName`. For me, the explanation is about `ArrayAccess`,  whose grammar is correct: `ExpressionName [ Expression ]`

Comment: You're right that `Primary` cannot be `ExpressionName`, but again that's by design. `id.id` (or, for that matter, just `id`) is not a `Primary`, but rather an `ExpressionName` (which can be reached from `Postfix`, but not from `Primary`). The reason for that is an ambiguity involving array accesses, which is what the note is talking about. The note only mentions plain identifiers, but the same logic applies to `id.id` (note that `id.id` could also be a type name, just like `id` could be a type name).

Comment: @sepp2k I see your points but your argument does not solve the problem that the grammar of `FieldAccess`, i.e. `Primary . Identifier`  cannot yield something like `obj.x`.

Comment: `FieldAccess` can't derive `obj.x` - that's true. And you're right that my arguments do not change that - it's a fact and can't be changed. But why is that a problem? I mean I get why it's counter-intuitive (as the note in the spec admits as well), but as long as `Expression` can derive `obj.x` (via `PostfixExpression` and then `ExpressionName`), why is it a problem that `FieldAccess` can't?

Comment: @sepp2k I see. Thanks! But if the grammar is correct, it is really unnatural that  `this.x` is a FieldAccess while `obj.x` is an `Expression`. In addition, from the explanation of the grammar “... but not for FieldAccess because this uses an identifier directly”, I tend to think that `FieldAccess` indeed uses an identifier directly; but its production rule uses `Primary` which cannot cannot be an identifier.

Comment: If `Primary` can't be ultimately an identifier there are much bigger problems than this.

Comment: The `FieldAccess` grammar notes constructs which ultimately lead to a field access production. In contrast, expressions of the form `identifier` or `identifier . anotherIdentifier` *may* be a field access, but could also be a type name. Depending on the context, a parser can not even tell whether such an `ExpressionName` is a field access or a type, as that requires resolving the names against a current class path (including traversal of type hierarchies and so on).

Comment: @Holger Thank you. Now I understand that `FieldAccess` only lists out unambiguous cases. So I assume that after parsing the ambiguous parts will finally be converted to constructs such as, a field access or a type. Is it true?   
I also looked at the ‘already answered’ question you pointed to, but I still do not understand why this is a problem in parsing. I assume that, if the ‘context’ requires remaining text (tokens), we can lookahead or use synthesised attributes; if the ‘context’ requires parsed parts, we can use inherited attributes. Will you kindly give any comment on this?

Comment: See for example `foo.bar();`. `foo` can be a field, but it could also be a local variable or a type (when `bar()` is a `static` method). Even better for `foo.bar.baz();`, where `foo.bar` could be a qualified type name, but if not, `foo` can be a field, a local variable or a type, whereas `bar` can be a field or a nested class. To find out, what it actually is, you need do resolve the names, considering the nested lexical scopes, the imports and the inheritance, which requires looking into other classes in the current class path. That’s outside the scope of a *parser*.